# Vuetify.js v-data-table sorting with only 2 states (asc & desc)

Tags: sorting, vuetify.js

Using Vuetify.js, I have a v-data-table with custom sorting.  The clickable header sort icons support 3 states: 1) Ascending (arrow icon), 2) Descending (arrow icon opposite direction), and "no sort" (arrow icon grayed out).  How can I get rid of the the "no sort" option and force only ascending or descending as the supported states or actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to disable "no sort" state, you can use **must-sort** prop.

But this prop will not set an *initial* sorting for you. Columns will still be unsorted by default. To restrict this, you need to define **sort-by** and **sort-desc** props. You can also show a sorting number badges then using **multi-sort** prop.

So the answer is: *to allow* initial "no sort" state, use this code:

```
<v-data-table
  ...
  must-sort
></v-data-table>
```

And *to restrict* initial "no sort" state, use this code:

```
<v-data-table
  ...
  must-sort
  multi-sort
  :sort-by="['calories', 'fat', 'carbs', 'protein', 'iron']"
  :sort-desc="[false, true, false, false, false]"
></v-data-table>
```

[Codepen with working example](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/mdMNbwX)